# getJSON parse error on validating JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, getjson

I am trying to use some JSON with JS that is output by a PHP script I control. The output validates fine at http://jsonlint.com/ but when I try to use it with $.getJSON it returns a parse error:

This is the non-descriptive error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

This is the source of the JSON: http://novaramedia.com/api/txt/

And this is my jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('http://novaramedia.com/api/txt/?callback=?', function(data) {

    console.log(data);

}).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);

});
```

The errorThrown variable logs as: `Error {}`

The JSON is output in a very normal basic way, with a PHP array input into json_encode. Here are the output lines of the script:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
die(json_encode($output));
```

The PHP script is almost exactly the same as one used for another JSON endpoint [ http://novaramedia.com/api/fm/ ] which getJSON doesnt have problems with. The only real difference is the value of 'content' which is HTML straight from a wordpress post content.

Very frustrating problem so any help much appreciated :}

Comment: That extra ?callback=? Makes me this the server is returning JSONP (which wouldn't parse as valid json (I'm typing this on my iPhone so I can't test this theory)

Comment: @DaveChen you are totally right. That was the difference between this PHP script and the other endpoints. I must have missed it as I added this endpoint after the other 2. Thanks very much. Please feel free to answer this question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For JSONP you need to have a callback function prepended.

Example:

```
jQuery({...})
```

The endpoint such as `http://novaramedia.com/api/txt/?callback=jQuery` should return a response between `jQuery( ... json output ... )`.

To expand:

You could use `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: \'http://remote-site.com\'');` and then access your  data freely from another domain.

The advantage would be that other people wouldn't be able to use jsonp on it, but maybe that was your intention in the first place.

Comment: Yes my outputting PHP should have been this `header("Content-type: application/json");
$json = json_encode($output);
echo isset($_GET['callback'])
    ? "{$_GET['callback']}($json)"
    : $json;`

Comment: thanks again @Dave Chen. It is almost always the assumptions where the most annoying bugs are.